# Sql joining query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a Query

```
SELECT foodjoint_id FROM provider_food_joints WHERE foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'";
```

Now I have to select all Info from another table which have a foodjoint_id  filed

```
SELECT * from menu_item where foodjoint_id = THOSE ID
```

I have to join those two Query

Comment: Also, you should use parameterized queries instead of concatenating your variables in your query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IN clause in your condition:

```
SELECT * from menu_item where foodjoint_id IN (
    SELECT foodjoint_id FROM provider_food_joints WHERE foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT i.menu_item 
FROM menu_item i 
JOIN provided_food_joints pfj 
ON (pfj.id = i.foodjoin_id)
WHERE i.foodjoin_id = 5
```

This is basically how a join statement works.
Check out [this tutorial](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php) for more information on different kind of joins

In your case - as suggested by nadirs - `JOIN` statements would be more useful.

Comment: I think what he means is joining two queries, rather than writing a query that joins two tables

Comment: Since he works with `foodjoin_id` and requests all info from the `menu_item table`. So I believe a join would be more useful

Comment: You could add this in your answer, like saying JOINs are more useful than nested queries in this situation

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * from menu_item where foodjoint_id in( SELECT foodjoint_id FROM provider_food_joints WHERE foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM menu_item WHERE foodjoint_id = (SELECT foodjoint_id FROM provider_food_joints WHERE foodjoint_name='".$foodjoint_name."'");
```

Hope  this is what your are asking? or be specific about the question